# Conventions for the PATH variable's value

Tags: environment-variables, path, administration, conventions

I am looking for best practices, or at least conventions, for the `PATH` variable's value.

In particular, I would like to know

1. is there any preferred/recommended ordering for the `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, and `/usr/local/bin` directories in the value of `PATH`?
2. are there any downsides to including `/sbin`, `/usr/sbin`, and/or `/usr/local/sbin` in a non-root user's `PATH` variable?

Regarding (1), my uninformed opinion is that these paths should appear in the order

```
..:/usr/local/bin:...:/usr/bin:...:/bin:...
```

...in the `PATH` variable.  The thinking here (to the extent there is any) is that `/usr/local/bin` may be where a local installation would put a "local" override of a command that may also exist under `/usr/bin`.  By the same token (and now really stretching it!), `/usr/bin` may contain distro-/vendor-level overrides to commands that traditionally live under `/bin`.

I realize that the above is 99% fantasy.  That's why I am asking this question.

In a similarly hallucinatory vein, I seem to recall the notion that the commands in `*/sbin` directories are meant for folks with superuser privileges, and it would confuse the regular users' little brains to make these commands available to them.  In other words, the `PATH` variable for regular users should not include any `*/sbin` paths.

Be that as it may, I don't recall ever coming across a system that included `*/sbin` paths in the initial setting of the `PATH` variable (by this I mean the setting of `PATH` that each user gets before his/her shell initialization scripts are run), and I wonder why this is so.

Comment: This seems rather OS-dependent. OSX and other BSD variants are going to be different from Linux-based distros, for example.  There is probably some variation even within either camp. The safest bet might be that the "conventions" arise from a default install of whatever OS you have at hand.  If those conventions clash with "best practice," that feedback should probably go upstream to the developers of distros, to improve the as-installed security of a default installation.

Answer (score 0):

1. yes and no. There is no specific rule on the order. It is more along the lines: if I have a tool `xyz` in `/bin` and in `/usr/bin` - and these are not links to the same tool but genuinely different tools - which one should be executed by default?

And yes, "local overrides" do play a huge role in that decision. So the suggested `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin` does make sense. But it is really rare to find a case with overriding. It can happen, in theory, but in practice...

Even if a super-user finds a better version of `ls` - it would either be installed system-wide into normal `/bin` or not installed at all, since "standard tools should be maintained on distributive level". And if you are using a commercial version of Linux - you would be legally forbidden to install different version of the system tool.

You can install for yourself, but in this case, the new version goes to `/home/user/bin`, so this is really the only source of possible override.

2. `/sbin`, as well as `/usr/sbin` are designed to keep tools for administrator and regular user does not them. They are usually included in root's personal PATH (from `/root/.bashrc` for example).

So you are correct, it is largely for not confusing regular users, and do not tempting them.